# Meteor user helper hangs off after update

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I have this helper:

```
agreed: function (){
        if (Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId(), profile: {agreedTermsOfUse: 'true'}}))
            return true;
    }
```

On the page where I check it I have this:

```
{{#unless agreed}}
      agree form
{{else}}
   Create item form.
    {{list of item}}
{{/unless}}
```

So far, all goes well. The user signs up then he can create an item and it renders on the list of items..

Now, I've added another Meteor.call, which when getting the success call back on the client, for the creating item, it adds the item id to the users' profile.hasItems.

Then after getting succes for that method, "unless" returns false, and I have to submit the agree to form again.

What am I missing? Thanks.

```
"submit .create_restaurant": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = event.target.create_restaurant.value;
    Meteor.call('CreateRest', Meteor.userId(), text, function(error, result){
        if(error){

        }else{
                console.log(result, Meteor.userId());
                Meteor.call('userRestaurants', result, Meteor.userId(), function (error, result) {

                    if (error) {
                        alert(123);
                    } else {
                        console.log(result);
                    }

                })

        }
    }
    );
    event.target.create_restaurant.value = "";
}
```

methods:

```
'CreateRest': function(user_id, title) {
    check(title, String);
    check(user_id, String);
    return callback = Restaurants.insert({
        createdBy: user_id,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        title: title
    });

},

'userRestaurants': function(rest_id, createdBy) {
    var restId = checkHelper(rest_id, createdBy);
    if(restId)
    console.log(rest_id, createdBy);
    {
    var callback = Meteor.users.update(
        createdBy,
        {$addToSet: {'profile.hasRestaurants': restId}}
    );
    return callback;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the method code and call callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're seeing the behaviour that you are, but I do know that you have other problems to sort out first :)

1. You have a huge security hole - you're passing the user id through to the method from the client. That means that anyone can simply open the browser console and create a restaurant with any user id they like as the owner. Instead, use this.userId in the method to get the id of the caller.
2. Why the round trip to the server? Just have the first method update the client.

So, something like this (untested, written by hand here):

```
"submit .create_restaurant": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = event.target.create_restaurant.value;
    Meteor.call('CreateRest',text, function(error, result){
        if(error){
            alert(123);
        }else{
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    event.target.create_restaurant.value = "";
}
```

and:

```
'CreateRest': function(user_id, title) {
    check(title, String);
    check(this.userId, String);

    userId = this.userId;

    Restaurants.insert({
        createdBy: userId,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        title: title
    }, function(err, restId) {
       if (err) throw new Meteor.Error(err);
       Meteor.users.update(
        userId,
        {$addToSet: {'profile.hasRestaurants': restId}},
        function (err, res) {
           if (err) throw new Meteor.Error(err);
           return restId;
        }
      );
    });
```

Once that's implemented properly it might start working. If it doesn't then the issue isn't related to the code you're posting.

Finally note that from a schema perspective it's *really* odd that that you have profile.hasRestaurants. To find the restaurants that a user has you should just do a find on the Restaurants collection.

Comment: thanks, I moved the userId from the call, and moved the callback to the method. I've replaced the last line of the callback: if (err) throw new Meteor.Error(err);
           return restId;
with :
if (err) throw new Meteor.Error(err);
                    console.log(restId);
                    return restId;
and I'm getting: undefined "d8BoKQsfps2WszMpS"

But still it displays the "agree to terms" after submitting. No errors.

Comment: It might not be necessary at this scenario, but generally speaking I would like to keep user's data in it's profile (like previous orders, favorites, etc", and I want to know that it is possible and I won't get this kind of issues.

Comment: Great. So please mark my answer as correct and give it an upvote ;)

Comment: Done, I still need some points for my votes to appear. So it looks like a meteor issue?

Comment: I don't think so, but I can't see you latest code. Perhaps post another question now?